# Linq to entities vb - Relationships causing troubles

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am programming in vb using linq to entities. Suppose I have 2 tables in my database. the first one called PARENT and the second CHILD. In CHILD I have a column named parent_id with which I created a foreign key constraint.
The problem is when I want to use the data from CHILD in my vb code using LINQ to entities, parent_id does not exist. Something like this is available : CHILD.PARENT. So I tried CHILD.PARENT.parent_id and got this : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".
The solution I've used so far is get rid of the relationship.
Can someone help me with this please?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: We can't really help you debug code that we can't see.  It sounds like your PARENT property is not being populated and lazy loading isn't kicking in.  You could try using [`Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx) to eagerly load the PARENT property, perhaps something like `Dim child = (From c In db.Children.Include(Function(x) x.PARENT) Where ...).SingleOrDefault()`.  Of course, there could be other issues, so this is just a guess.

Comment: I've found the solution to my problem. I just had to use the include function like this:
Dim child= (From c In context.CHILD.Include("PARENT") Select c).FirstOrDefault. Thanks for your help @Mark.